# Not able to write php file in php

Tags: php, html

I am able to write .txt file with the following code but unable to do so with php files(existing or newly created with the following code) on localhost.

Also it echo  string length correctly without any error notice or warning

```
<?php
$file = fopen("test.php","w");
echo fwrite($file,"do not vote me down");
fclose($file);
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post more details of the problem. Whether the file is being created, if it is being created, are the contents written to the file, etc...

Comment: @captainblack yes file is created for the first time but then i cant make any further changes to it (php files)

Comment: do i need to use chmod or something?

Comment: are the contents of the file empty or the content got saved?

Comment: It shows the same old content

Comment: Have you tried the die() option as suggested by @surani?

Comment: yes sir, its working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may be a ownership problem. try do  `chmod -R 775 /var/www/folder` and/or  `chown -R domain:www-data /var/www/folder` - where domain is the user of that particular virtualhost or www-data

Also to update a file instead rewrite you can use append option - adding `+` will help to create the file first time if it is not exists.

```
$file = fopen("test.php","a+");
echo fwrite($file,"do not vote me down ab");
fclose($file);
```

And If you want to change the ownership of the file you can use Php `chown` function-

```
chown('test.php','apache');
```

Too change permission of file or folder recusively use this code -

```
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type d -exec chmod 0750 {} +");
exec ("find /path/to/folder -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +");
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your file will not open so you can add die() function after fopen(), review below code :-

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "Mickey Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Minnie Mouse\n";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Nah its still the same

Comment: problem is only with php file that I can not overwrite them

Comment: make sure .txt file is store in same directory with .php file.

Comment: <?php
$myfile = fopen("test.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,"do not vote me down");
fclose($myfile);
?>

Comment: just remove echo from second line @sam

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. I can rewrite the content, as long as test.php has appropriate file permission.

Comment: Ok ! can i change permission of file in php before opening it in write mode

Comment: You can. chmod function will help you achieve that. Alternatively, you can create a sub folder and set permission to that folder instead. lets say if you create a folder 'test_data' and set recursive permission to that folder, any file created under that folder will inherit the same permissions.

Comment: <?php
 $file = fopen("test_data/test.php","w");
 echo fwrite($file,"do not vote me down rewritting 12345");
 fclose($file);
?>

Comment: I tried it this way but to no success
<?php

chmod("test.php",0755);

$file = fopen("test.php","w") or die("Unable to open file!");

echo fwrite($file,"do not vote me down");

fclose($file);

?>

Comment: try moving that file inside a folder, set 777 for that folder and file and try to execute the code. IMO, it is a permission issue.